# Issue of casting Node neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

My code is below, As per the documentation it should have given me the node values but it is throwing me exception

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Node
 at com.neo4j.performance.FetchData.main(FetchData.java:32)
```

I'm using Neo4j 2.2.2.

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Result;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import java.util.Iterator; 
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil;




import com.neo4j.enitites.Global;

public class FetchData {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  
        {

         String nodeResult = null;
         try ( Transaction ignored = Global.db.beginTx();
                  Result result = Global.db.execute( "MATCH path=()-[:route_1*]-() RETURN nodes(path) AS result" ) )
            {
                // START SNIPPET: items
                Iterator<Node> n_column = result.columnAs( "result" );
                for ( Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable( n_column ) )
                {
                    nodeResult = node + ": " + node.getProperty( "StationCode" );
                }
                // END SNIPPET: items


            }

         System.out.println(nodeResult);
        }
}
```

I've searched for the error but only 2 or 3 posts are there those also not working. Has anyone came across with this issue or there is something wrong in this code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this snippet instead inside the transaction try-with-resources block:

```
        for (Object cell : IteratorUtil.asIterable(result.columnAs("result"))) {
            Iterable<Node> nodes = (Iterable<Node>) cell;
            for (Node n : nodes) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where has the `nodeResult` gone to? Here we just print out something.