# Java Neo4j Cypher Or Match

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph were user can have a post and also can have a friend that have a post , the friend can be followed or not .
how can i query all the posts by the user and the friends that he is following ?
I tried this :

```
  " MATCH (u1:User)-[:POSTED]->(p1:Post)"
+ " WHERE u1.username =~ '"+user+"'"
+ " OPTIONAL MATCH (u3:User)-[:FOLLOWING]->(u2:User)-[:POSTED]->(p2:Post),"
+ " (u3:User)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(u2:User)"
+ " WHERE u3.username =~ '"+user+"' return u1.username, u1.name,"
                        + "p1 ,u2.username, u2.name , p2";
```

but this query returns duplicates, lets say we have our user and a friend .
the frien have one post and the user have two , the query returns the friend post twice its like for every **MATCH** the query returns also the result of **OPTIONAL MATCH** .

to further exaplain:

```
(u:User)-[:POSTED]->(p:Post)
(u:User)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(u2:User)
(u:User)-[:FOLLOWING]->(u2:User)-[:POSTED]->(p2:Post)
```

these are the relationships that exist what i want is all Posts (:Post) that meet those relationships without duplicates and preferably with single query .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your query is much more complex than it needs to be. This simpler query should be equivalent. I assume that `{user}` is supplied as a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html).

```
MATCH (u1:User {username: {user}})-[:POSTED]->(p1:Post)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (u1)-[:FOLLOWING]->(u2:User)-[:POSTED]->(p2:Post),
  (u1)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(u2)
RETURN u1.username, u1.name, p1, u2.username, u2.name, p2;
```

The reason you get multiple rows with the same `p2` values is because your `RETURN` clause is returning values related to `u1` and `u2` together. If there are `N` u1/p1 results and `M` u2/p2 results, then you'd get `N*M` result rows.

To get a result with N rows (with one row per `u1/p2` result), you can use something like this query:

```
MATCH (u1:User {username: {user}})-[:POSTED]->(p1:Post)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (u1)-[:FOLLOWING]->(u2:User)-[:POSTED]->(p2:Post),
  (u1)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(u2)
RETURN
  u1.username, u1.name, p1,
  COLLECT({username: u2.username, name: u2.name, p2: p2}) AS friends;
```

Each result row will have a `friends` collection with the data for each relevant friend.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i can't iterate over the collection i tried the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554217/issue-of-casting-node-neo4j didnt help , i still get the error scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Node

Comment: That SO question is not suitable for the collection. You should not be trying to iterate over a column that contains just nodes. And being unable to iterate over the results is really a separate problem. You should create a new question.

Comment: i did manage to iterate over them using : [code]          scala.collection.convert.Wrappers.IteratorWrapper it =  ((SeqWrapper) row.get("friends")).iterator();
          while(it.hasNext()){
           MapWrapper m = (MapWrapper)it.next();
           Node n = (Node)m.get("p2");
           for (String key : n.getPropertyKeys()) {
            
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " +  n.getProperty(key));
           }
          }[/code] the question is if scala.collection.convert.Wrappers package is included in every java installation ?

Comment: this doesnt return anything if the user have no posts , which in this case i want the followed friends